# How to delete column Z (there are no headers) in excel using python

Tags: python

I want to delete column Z in excel using python, tried below code but didn't work

```
from openpyxl import Workbook
import openpyxl 

srcfile = openpyxl.load_workbook('QualityReview Business-Template-xx.xlsx', read_only=False)

df.drop(columns=df.columns[83], inplace=True)
srcfile.save('QualityReview Business-Template-xx.xlsx')
```

error message : IndexError: index 83 is out of bounds for axis 0 with size 1

Comment: why would column z be indexed as 83 and not something closer to say 26? How does `df` relate to `srcfile`?

Comment: Does `srcfile.active.delete_cols(26, 1)` do what you seek? Off the top of my head I'm not sure if that would column "z" or "aa" so test on something disposable.

Comment: openpyxl numbers rows/columns from 1, so 26 should indeed be Z.

Comment: Try looking at [Deleting rows and columns](https://openpyxl.readthedocs.io/en/stable/editing_worksheets.html#deleting-rows-and-columns).